# Ansible fetch from various hosts various files

Tags: ansible

I am newbie to ansible. My goal is to fetch files from various servers. Each server has different path where a file is stored. Destination path is always the same.

I have the following:

```
- name: fetch files
  hosts: hosts
  tasks:
    - name: fetch files
      fetch:
       src: /home/ubuntu/test1/testing1.txt
       dest: /home/ubuntu/
       flat: yes
       when: inventory_hostname == "ansible1"

    - name: fetch files2
      fetch:
       src: /home/ubuntu/test2/testing2.txt
       dest: /home/ubuntu/
       flat: yes
       when: inventory_hostname == "ansible2"
```

My inventory file is:

```
[hosts]
ansible1
ansible2
```

When I execute:

ansible-playbook fetch.yml -i inventory.txt

The output is following:

```
PLAY [fetch files] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [ansible2]
ok: [ansible1]

TASK [fetch files] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [ansible1]
fatal: [ansible2]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "file not found: /home/ubuntu/test1/testing1.txt"}

TASK [fetch files2] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [ansible1]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "file not found: /home/ubuntu/test2/testing2.txt"}

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ansible1                   : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
ansible2                   : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Why it tried to run it for other hosts when the condition is specific for one?
Second question - why for the second task "fetch file2" it actually doesnt fetch it at all, although the file is present on the remote machine?

I am using for the test and development multipass and ubuntu. SSH keys are imported on the target machines.

Thanks in advance for help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a dictionary in [*vars*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable). For example,

```yaml
shel> cat group_vars/all/testing.yml
testing_paths:
  ansible1: /home/ubuntu/test1/testing1.txt
  ansible2: /home/ubuntu/test2/testing2.txt
```

and use it for the task

```yaml
    - fetch:
        src: "{{ testing_paths[inventory_hostname] }}"
        dest: /home/ubuntu/
        flat: yes
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for showing me the direction :) it works

Comment: Hi, I added more hosts to the list testing_paths group_vars with different sources. Some of these hosts are in the list twice with different paths. But ansible complains about it

WARNING]: While constructing a mapping from /home/ubuntu/ansible/group_vars/all/testing.yml, line 2, column 3, found a duplicate dict key (ansible3). Using last defined value only.
And others

is it possible to have same hosts multiple times with different sources in one group_vars  list?

Comment: Which one would you like to use? (*"Some of these hosts are in the list twice with different paths."*).

Comment: Lets say, ansible2 contains two paths of files I need to fetch:

`testing_paths:
  ansible1: /home/ubuntu/test1/testing1.txt
  ansible2: /home/ubuntu/test2/testing2.txt
  ansible2: /home/somewhereelse/testing_of_fetch/testing2.txt`

Comment: You can have lists of the paths `testing_paths: ansible1: [path1] ansible2: [path1, path2]`. Open a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Your indentation is wrong. `when` needs to be at the same level as `fetch`, not below it.

```yml
    - name: fetch files
      fetch:
        src: /home/ubuntu/test1/testing1.txt
        dest: /home/ubuntu/
        flat: yes
      when: inventory_hostname == "ansible1"
```

The missing indendation results in both tasks being run on both hosts. Since the first task fails on the host `ansible2` because the `src` path doesn't exist there, Ansible ends the playbook for this host and no further tasks are executed for it. The second task then fails on the remaining host, again, because the `src` path doesn't exist there.

---

But you could make this much easier by saving the src path as a host variable and reduce it to a single task

*host_vars/ansible1.yml*

```yml
src_path: /home/ubuntu/test1/testing1.txt
```

*host_vars/ansible2.yml*

```yml
src_path: /home/ubuntu/test2/testing2.txt
```

*playbook.yml*

```yml
- name: fetch files
  hosts: hosts
  tasks:
    - name: fetch files
      fetch:
        src: "{{ src_path }}"
        dest: /home/ubuntu/
        flat: yes
```

Comment: Same here, thanks a lot for help.